# Function like get_meta_tags() but for strings, not files?

Tags: php, tags, meta

`get_meta_tags()` requires a `filename` as its parameter. What if I have the HTML loaded into a `$string` for various reasons (cURL, for example), and I need to extract meta tags from that?

Is there an alternative which accepts `strings`?

Comment: So in this scenario you can't use functions like file_put_contents and file_get_contents?